# Magento community and enterprise development difference

Tags: magento-enterprise, development, magento-ce

I'm planning to use the enterprise edition for the production server, but it will take a few months to get the custom development ready, so my question is if we develop the code based on the community edition, will it be a problem to migrate to enterprise edition later?

Comment: do not make things complicated, just download Enterprise and work. eh??

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise has 41 modules that are separate from the community edition code base. These include modules which cover areas such as:

- Search
- Indexing
- Catalog
- Page Caching
- Reward Points

So while the core magento Mage_* functionality should be expected to be the same, depending on what functionality you are looking to make use of it may very well be that the Enterprise functionality replaces or augments how it is in use.

If you plan to build on Enterprise, then you would be best getting the Enterprise License setup, and develop the site on that rather than build it blindly and hope that you do not run into problems.

Comment: Yes, I do want to get the Enterprise license, but it's so costly, so trying to postpone purchase time until we deploy on production environment, does Magento offer developer license for their Enterprise version?

Comment: If cost is a concern, then perhaps you should consider if Enterprise Edition is something which you need? I do believe there is a developer license available but it is also a paid for one.